# Autofac : Resolve instance having type and name?

Tags: types, get, instance, autofac

I have next Code in frm_main

```
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterInstance<FrmMainCommunicator>(new FrmMainCommunicator(this, this.pb_publisherStatus)).Named<ICommunicationProvider>("FrmMainCommunicator");
        builder.Update(SPInjector.Instance.Container);
```

FrmMainCommunicator implements ICommunicationProvider interface.

Then, in another project, y need the instance of the FrmMainCommunicator.

I need something like :

```
ICommunicationProvider provider = DIInjector.Get<ICommunicationProvider>().Named("FrmMainCommunicator");
```

Comment: What is `DIInjector`? What is your question? Is something not working as expected or you get an exception or.. ?

Answer (score 1):

If `DIInjector` is an Autofac container, you need the `ResolveNamed` method:

```
DIInjector.ResolveNamed<ICommunicationProvider>("FrmMainCommunicator")
```